# issue when ifisset added to code

Tags: php, mysql, database

some explenation

http://koopjesidee.nl/images/6755185029021696.jpg

in my database i have a column named new_label
when its a new product its set as new
when no new product the colums is empty

i want the class="main-label new-label" to be disabled when there nothing in that column
now as you see from the image, there is always a orange cirkel (as set in class main-label) even when column is empty

This is my code

```
<!-- select products from database -->
<?php
$query = "select * from contentwhere cat = 4  order by rand() LIMIT 18";
$result = $db->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
$url =detail($row);

<!-- content on main page -->
echo '
<div class="item">
<div class="product-item">
<div class="main-label new-label"><span>'.$row['new_label'].'</span></div>
<div class="product-image"><a href="'.$row['url'].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$row['picture_big'].'" alt="'.$row['name'].'"></a></div>
<div class="product-item-details">
<div class="product-item-name"> <a href="'.$row['url'].'" target="_blank">'.$row['name'].'</a> </div>
<div class="price-box"> <span class="price">&euro;'.$row['price'].'</span> <del class="price old-price">'.$row['from_price'].'</del> </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>';
                            }?>
```

I want add if `isset` like this so when there is no text in class=new-label class main-label new-label is disabled column in my database is new_label

```
 <div class="item">
<div class="product-item">

<!-- ISSUE -->
if (isset($_row['new_label']!='')) {

<div class="main-label new-label"><span>'.$row['new_label'].'</span></div>;
} else {
<div class="main-label new-label"><span></span></div>;
                                            }

 <!-- HTTP ERROR 500 -->


<div class="product-image"><a href="'.$row['url'].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$row['picture_big'].'" alt="'.$row['name'].'"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `isset()` on the result of an expression, it can only be a variable. In fact, it will result in a fatal error if you try (which is probably why you received a 500 server error).

So you can probably change this line:

```
if (isset($_row['new_label']!='')) {
```

To this:

```
if (isset($_row['new_label'])) {
```

`isset()` returns a boolean anyway, so it doesn't make sense to compare it to a string.

Read more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED MYSELF GUYS

'.$row['new_label'].'';} ?>

thanks anyway